# What exactly is the difference between Part and Extract?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-comparison

From the statement in the documentation:

> Extract[expr,{i,j,…}] is equivalent to Part[expr,i,j,…].

So basically `Extract` is just a listable version of `Part`. So I look at the following example:

```
expr = f[g[1, 2], {h[3],i[4]}];
```

Let's take some parts out as follows:

```
{Part[expr,1,2],Part[expr, 2, All, 1]}
```

> {2, {3, 4}}

Now I try to combine the multiple `Part`s using a single `Extract`:

```
{Extract[expr,{1,2}], Extract[expr,{2,All,1}]}
Extract[expr, {{1, 2}, {2, All, 1}}]
```

and it fails. But why? Isn't it the purpose of `Extract` to be able to combine multiple `Part`s commands into a single `Extract`?

---

Issue recently discussed on [Live CEOing Ep 488: Language Design in Wolfram Language [SubValues, List, Extract and More]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svvgvSsUrho)
 and a potential solution may be coming in a future version.

Comment: `All` is not a position per se. Neither is a `Span[]`.  The purpose of `Extract` is to extract parts found by `Position`. (The previous sentence is my opinon, not necessarily a fact.) -- There's also `Extract[expr, {p1, p2,...}, Hold]`, which `Part` does not do.

Comment: Another difference, `Extract` has an operator form, `Part` does not.

Comment: To quote the docs: "The position specifications used by `Extract` have the same form as those returned by `Position`"

Answer (score 6):

`Extract` works with standard positions specifications, the same ones returned by `Position`, and used by functions like `Delete` or `ReplacePart`. These functions are all cross-compatible: the output of one works with the others. `Extract` is simple, predictable, and thus very suitable for working with programmatically generated position specifications. The number of extracted elements will be the same as the number of position specifications you pass in.

However, writing positions specifications manually is cumbersome. There is no concise way to extract multiple parts at a certain depth, e.g. `data[[2, 3, {4,5}]]`. `All` and `;;` cannot be used (as they are also meant for specific levels). These is why we have `Part`.

In summary,

- I use `Extract` when dealing with positions specifications generated by other functions, usually `Position`. `Extract` takes a *list* of position specifications, each one of which must be complete and stand on its own.
- I use `Part` when specifying what to extract manually. We can write what to extract separately at each level/depth of the expression. Thus a single part specification can refer to multiple parts of the expression at the same time.