# Fast element extraction

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list $A$ of $\sim$ $3.10^6$ complex numbers.

I have another list $B$ of 15000 positions  `B={1,25,55,100000,...}`.

I want to extract the elements from list $A$ whose position is in list $B$

I do `C=Table[A[[i]],{i,B}]`

But this is is super slow, in fact for a reason unknown to me, it is fast and then when `Length@B` is greater than 200, it becomes slow.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: `a = RandomComplex[{-2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I}, 20]` `b = {1, 3, 5, 7}` and use: `a[[b]]`

Comment: This solves the problem @Syed, post it as answer

Comment: In addition, as pointed out [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/213567/106), `Extract` has an operator form (and, if one wishes, something like the following is possible: `Extract[a,Transpose[{b}],ReIm]` ) [ `a` and `b` as defined by Syed below]

Comment: Written in operator form: `Extract[Transpose[{b}]] [ReIm[a]]` as I understand it. I am running v12.2.0 on Win7-x64. The three argument version of `Extract` shared by @user1066 is new to me and much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Part can take a list of positions. You can just do:

```
C=A[[B]]
```

At the scale you describe, this seems to speed things up by 2 orders of magnitude.

**NOTE** The above uses A,B,C to align with the original post, but C is already defined in the System` context, so the solution won't actually work when executed exactly as presented.

Answer (score 7):

**Using `Part`**:

```
SeedRandom[1];
a = RandomComplex[{-2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I}, 20]
b = {1, 3, 5, 7}
a[[b]]
```

---

**Using `Extract`:**

Let's say you want to extract all entries where the absolute value is > 1.8;

```
pos = Position[a, x_ /; Abs[x] > 1.8, Infinity]
```

> {{2}, {6}, {13}, {15}, {16}}

Notice the braces around each entry. This works directly with `Extract`:

```
Extract[a, pos]
```

> ```
> {-1.55432 - 1.48472 I, -1.73704 + 1.27987 I, -0.308597 - 1.95266 I, 
>  1.90869 + 1.15922 I, 1.30065 - 1.95209 I}
> ```